# How to express expectation of product in terms of other moments?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I'm having trouble with this problem. $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $a$ and $b$ are constants. Assume that $E(Y|X) = aX + b$, where $E(.)$ is the expected value operator. How do I express $E(YX)$ as a function only of the first two moments of $X$? What should be my approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $XE(Y|X)=E(XY|X)$. this gives $E(XY)=E(E(XY|X))=E(aX^{2}+bX)=aEX^{2}+bEX$.